# Password-protected page redirecting to frontpage when I enter the password

Tags: password

I've enabled built-in password protection on one of my pages. The password form shows up, I enter a password, press *Submit* button and I'm redirected to my front page.

Now if I revisit the protected page, it will be unlocked (if the password was correct). But I think after I enter the password, I should land directly on the page I'm trying to access, right?

I'm using Wordpress 3.5.2 with a custom theme. What I've tried:

- tested it on another blog with WP 3.5.2
- switched theme to unmodified Twenty Twelve
- disabled all plugins
- clean WP install on a local server

No luck with any of these, still the same problem - I'm redirected to the server's root (i.e. `example.com/`, not `example.com/wordpress` or `example.com/wordpress/passpage`).

Is it a bug or intended behavior? Is there any workaround I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a problem with my browser blocking HTTP referrers.

Disabling referrer blocking or switching to another browser solves the issue.

([related Trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23412))